# [Oracle][TypeORM] PrimaryGeneratedColumn("increment") not working for bulk insert

Tags: oracle, typeorm

I have a simple entity in TypeORM 0.3.17 connected to an Oracle 19c instance

```
export class Zone extends BaseEntity {

        @PrimaryGeneratedColumn("increment")
        id: number
       
        @Column({nullable: false, unique: true, length: 100})
        name: string
}
```

Should work without any problems right?
I have a json with the data I want to insert, called `zones.json`:

```
[
  {
    "name": "ZONA 1"
  },
  {
    "name": "ZONA 2"
  }
]
```

But if I try to bulk insert with a simple code like this:

```
import zonesJSON from "./zones.json"
async function populateZones(): Promise<Zone[]> {
    let savedZones: Zone[] = await Zone.find();
    if (savedZones.length === 0) {
        savedZones = Zone.create(zonesJson as object[]) as Zone[];
        await Zone.insert(savedZones);
    }
    return savedZones;
}
```

I get the error:

```
ueryFailedError: ORA-01400: cannot insert NULL into (<schema>."zone"."id")
```

because TypeORM tries to insert the data like this:

```
INSERT INTO <schema>."zone"("id", "name")  SELECT NULL, :1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL  SELECT NULL, :2 FROM DUAL -- PARAMETERS: ["ZONA 1","ZONA 2"]
```

Giving a NULL id, and because of this Oracle does not apply the auto-incremented identifier, but throws the error. This is expected behavior from Oracle if the identity column is created with `GENERATED BY DEFAULT` instead of `GENERATED BY DEFAULT ON NULL`.

Inserting one-by-one works, but it's not a solution that I want or anyone wants...I just want to be able to do a basic transaction...

Is there any configuration that I can change in the TypeORM Datasource, Column Definition or Oracle server to solve this issue?

Thanks in advance!